# Tracking correct move list while using a stack to traverse a 2D maze

Tags: java, arrays, stack

So I'm working on an assignment and I'm completely stumped. I have to modify someone else's code for a program that uses a stack to mimic recursion and find its way through a 2D maze. I have to modify the program to display the correct path not including any cells that led to or are a dead end.

The way the program currently works is that it takes all possible moves from your current location, then pushes them to a stack in west, east, north, south order. Then it pops the top cell off the stack and moves to it. It repeats this process until it runs into a dead end, at which point it pops an older possibly location off the top of the stack and jumps back to it, continuing on from there, or if it finds the end it stops.

The problem I'm running into is that the program doesn't keep the moves once they're popped off the stack, so backtracking and marking incorrect cells isn't an option that way.

My question, more asking for advice I guess, what strategy should I try taking to mark the incorrect cells so that I can print only the correct ones at the end of the maze?

I can supply code if needed, but the program is pretty big and consists of several .java files.

Let me know if you need more info. I'm really just hoping for a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else out there that might stumble across this, I ended up writing a recursive algorithm that, when it's able to find its way to the end from a location, it marks it as part of the correct path, moves the starting location, resets the maze, and runs it again, repeating until it reaches the end.